# Robot Framework: Reading text file and creating dictionary with keys and array values

Tags: dictionary, robotframework

My text sample `.txt` file is `testing.txt` looks like this

```
city germany
language english
city france
Capital paris
Capital Delhi
```

Now i want a dictionary to be created like this

```
{city: germany, fance; language: english ; Capital: paris,Delhi}
```

My sample code is :

```
${my_dict}=    Create Dictionary
#@{keys}=    Get Dictionary Keys    ${key}
${data}    OperatingSystem.Get File    

C:\\Users\\cpt2deh\\Desktop\\cmptl\\Sprint19\\Testing\\pythonexercise-lib\\test\\Output2\\Testing.txt
    @{lines}    Split To Lines    ${data}
    Remove Values From List    ${lines}    ${EMPTY}
    :FOR    ${line}    IN    @{lines}
    \    ${key}    ${value}    Split String    ${line}                
    #\    Log to console    ${key}    
    #\    Log to console    ${value}
    \    Run Keyword If    '${key}'!= '${empty}'    Set To Dictionary    ${my_dict}    ${key}    ${value}
    \    Run Keyword If    '${value}'!='${empty}'    Append To List    ${my_dict}    ${key}    ${value}
    \    Set To Dictionary    ${my_dict}    ${key}    ${value}
    Log to console    ${my_dict}
```

Please help me  as I am not getting values in Array

Comment: The "dictionary" you presented isn't a valid python or json dictionary. Do you need something in the exact format you specify, or do you need a valid python dictionary? What debugging have you done? Have you verified that `${key}` and `${value}` are what you expect them to be?

Comment: Hi Brayan , The Dictionary created is in Robot Framework format.. and it is being created succesfully. Robot Framework in turn uses Python . Bit for some reasons I am not able to iterate thru keys and all multiple values to the same key as shown in expected result. As far as plain python is cosidered I am able to acieve this using Python 2.7. Yes key and Value are populated correctly...